# how to use getx text controller at text field? the data has changed bet UI don't

Tags: flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx, state-management

```
//my controller

class ControllerPesan extends GetxController {
  var namadepan = ''.obs;
  var namabelakang = ''.obs;
  var alamat = ''.obs;
  var total = ''.obs;

  TextEditingController controllernamadepan = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllernamabelakang = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controlleralamat = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllertotal = TextEditingController();

}
```

// another page to return text editing controller.

```
ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Color(0xFF023609),
          shadowColor: Colors.white,
          elevation: 5),
      onPressed: () {
        Obx(() => Text(pc.controllernamadepan.text));
        Obx(() => Text(pc.controllernamabelakang.text));
        Obx(
          () => Text(pc.controlleralamat.text),
        );
        Obx(
          () => Text(pc.controlleralamat.text),
        );
        alert(context, "Berhasil Memesan Tanaman !!!");
      },

      // alert(context, "Berhasil Memesan Tanaman !!!");
      child: const Text(
        "Pesan",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(height: 20), // Margin Bohongan
  //am i wrong at this?
    Text(
      'Berikut Rincian Pesanan Anda: ',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
    ),
    Text('Nama             : ${pc.namadepan} ${pc.namabelakang}',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
    Text('Alamat           : ${pc.alamat}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
    Text('Total               : ${pc.total}',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Text` widgets with `Obx`:

```
Obx(()=>Text('Nama             : ${pc.namadepan.value} ${pc.namabelakang.value}',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),),
```